# How to turn off magic quotes in PHP configuration file? I am using XAMPP

Tags: php, configuration, xampp, magic-quotes

What is the file? I have php.ini and php.ini-dist on my computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

php.ini-dist is the sample config file that comes with PHP, php.ini is the live config so you will need to set in this file

```
magic_quotes_gpc = off
magic_quotes_runtime = off
magic_quotes_sybase = off
```

Comment: Depending our your configuration, you'll also most likely need to restart your webserver for these changes to take effect. :-)

Comment: I changed the three equations to "off" and I restarted my web server, but the change doesn't take effect.

Comment: OK, it sounds like you'll need to check that PHP is reading the ini file you've updated. Simply output a page with <?php phpinfo(); ?> on it and this will list both the ini file in use and the magic quotes related settings.

Comment: Good suggestion. Thank Middaparka and Tim.