# Why is escape character being added to URL parameters?

Tags: php, apache, url, parameters, escaping

My `PHP` page is accepting a parameter in the URL.  This parameter is being assigned to a variable as follows:

```
$msg = $_REQUEST["msg"];
```

When the `HTTP` request is sent to the website, the parameter is sent as `"hello'"`, but when it gets to the `PHP` variable above it becomes `"hello\'"`.

Why is the backslash being inserted and what is inserting it?  Is it the web server?  How can I prevent this happening?

Comment: [PHP Magic Quotes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_quotes).

Comment: use string stripslashes ( string $str )

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to turn off magic quotes in PHP configuration file? I am using XAMPP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748001/how-to-turn-off-magic-quotes-in-php-configuration-file-i-am-using-xampp) or [How can I disable PHP magic quotes at runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153741/how-can-i-disable-php-magic-quotes-at-runtime)

Comment: @X-Factor: what do you mean?

Comment: @DCoder: PHP Magic Quotes is [DEPRECATED](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php).

Comment: @fnkr: that is pointed out in the very first paragraph of my link...

Answer (score 1):

Magic Quotes is running on you server. You should use **stripslashes($text)** function:

```
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
        $msg = stripslashes($_REQUEST["msg"]); 
   else $msg = $_REQUEST["msg"];
```

Answer (score -2):

It is being appended cause your single quote sign is a part of the string. If it would not be escaped - that's the meaning of the backslash - it might be that your string definition is terminated too soon.

Comment: Didn't downvote.. but that isn't the reason.